# Table in partial view not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display a table of jobs for a client sectioned by month year. The partial views evaluate and using `binding.pry` on each I can see that the correct values are there. The `_month_section.html.erb` date does not show, nor does the table in `_jobs.html.erb`

**clients_controller.rb**

```
def show
  if id = params[:id]
    if @client = current_user.clients.find_by_id(id.to_i) 
      if @client.jobs.count > 0
       @jobs_by_month = @client.jobs.group_by{|j| j.created_at.strftime('%B %Y')}
      end
    else
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end      
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if @client.jobs.count > 0 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-white">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Jobs</h4>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <%= render 'month_section' %>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```

**_month_section.html.erb**

```
<div class="month_section" >
    <% @jobs_by_month.each do |date, jobs| %>
         <div>
           <h3><%= date %></h3>
           <%= render partial: 'jobs', :locals => {:jobs => jobs } %>
         </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**_jobs.html.erb**

```
<div class="jobs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Start Time</th>
                      <th>End Time</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                      <tbody>
                         <% jobs.each do |job| %>
                             <tr>
                              <td><%= job.date%></td>
                              <td><%= job.start_time %></td>
                              <td><%= job.end_time %></td>
                            </tr>
                         <% end %>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like the problem at the first line of `_month_section.html.erb`, it should be `<div class="month_section" >`, right?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. However, correcting this does not fix the issue of the partial views not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out issue was due to a rogue non-terminated div tag on `show.html.erb` outside of the snippet I posted.